# Python uWSGI logs have no read permissions

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, logging, file-permissions, uwsgi

I am running a Python Flask server on uWSGI over an EC2 Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. The server is configured as follows:

```
[uwsgi]
http-socket    = :9000
plugin         = python
wsgi-file      = /path/to_wsgi.py
enable-threads = true
```

The logs, however, are created using root permissions without read access:

```
$ ls -ltrh /var/log/uwsgi/app
total 34M
-rw-r----- 1 root root 2.3M Jun  4 06:50 reporter-uwsgi.log.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root root  24M Jun  5 06:51 reporter-uwsgi.log.1
-rw-r----- 1 root root 8.4M Jun  5 17:27 reporter-uwsgi.log
```

This is an annoyance, because some of my scripts run as a normal user and parse these logs.

Any idea how to configure uWSGI to be written with global read permissions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the **logfile-chown** and **logfile-chmod** configuration options. Both can be set from the command line or in an `.ini` file.

Here is an example:

```
[uwsgi]
# ...
logto = /path/file_name.log
logfile-chown = username:groupname
logfile-chmod = 640
```

More information in the [documentation](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html#logfile-chown).